# File missing or incomplete package installed

Tags: dpkg

Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit terminal tells me the following:

```
dpkg: warning: Missing file from the list of files xserver-input-vmmouse xorg- package;
```

It is assuming package has no files currently installed. How can I correct or resolve this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Use the  command

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you get the same error try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg –configure -a` gives "post-installation script subprocess returned error" about "[some file]: not found"

Answer (score 0):

First try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get --purge remove
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq tspc
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then try reinstalling the program.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some files from the package has been deleted.

The best way is to re-install this package

```
sudo apt-get install --re-install xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
```